# How to read and store values from a text file into a dictionary. [python]

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, io

I'm trying to figure out how to open up a file and then store it's contents into a dictionary using the Part no. as the key and the other information as the value. So I want it to look something like this:

```
{Part no.: "Description,Price", 453: "Sperving_Bearing,9900", 1342: "Panametric_Fan,23400",9480: "Converter_Exchange,93859"}
```

I was able to store the text from the file into a list, but I'm not sure how to assign more than one value to a key. I'm trying to do this without importing any modules. I've been using the basic str methods, list methods and dict methods.

Comment: what version of python do you use?

Comment: What kind of file is that, is that just a normal txt file?

Comment: @nio I use python 3. It's just a txt file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a `txt` file like so

```
453     Sperving_Bearing    9900
1342    Panametric_Fan      23400
9480    Converter_Exchange  93859
```

You can just do

```
>>> newDict = {}
>>> with open('testFile.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            splitLine = line.split()
            newDict[int(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])


>>> newDict
{9480: 'Converter_Exchange,93859', 453: 'Sperving_Bearing,9900', 1342: 'Panametric_Fan,23400'}
```

You can get rid of the `----...` line by just checking if `line.startswith('-----')`.

**EDIT** - If you are sure that the first two lines contain the same stuff, then you can just do

```
>>> testDict = {"Part no.": "Description,Price"}
>>> with open('testFile.txt', 'r') as f:
        _ = next(f)
        _ = next(f)
        for line in f:
            splitLine = line.split()
            testDict[int(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])       
>>> testDict
{9480: 'Converter_Exchange,93859', 'Part no.': 'Description,Price', 453: 'Sperving_Bearing,9900', 1342: 'Panametric_Fan,23400'}
```

This adds the first line to the `testDict` in the code and skips the first two lines and then continues on as normal.

Comment: newDict[int(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:]).ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: Okay. Are you parsing the first line using this code too? Because that would give this error. You need to parse it separately. I posted the example text file.

Comment: Yeah, I am. The first part has to be included.

Comment: If you are sure that the first line is never going to change, then you can just add that to the dictionary in your code and skip the first two lines. I'll explain how by adding the code in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file into a list of lines like this:

```
lines = thetextfile.readlines()
```

You can split a single line by spaces using:

```
items = somestring.split()
```

Here's a principial example how to store a list into a dictionary:

```
>>>mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>>mydict = {}
>>>mydict['hello'] = mylist
>>>mydict['world'] = [4,5,6]
>>>print(mydict)
```

Containers like a tuple, list and dictionary can be nested into each other as their items.

To itereate a list you have to use a for statement like this:

```
for item in somelist:
    # do something with the item like printing it
    print item
```

Comment: If I were to split the texts by the newline character would it be possible to later split each of those lines by each word?

Comment: yes it would, you could read the whole file using `thetextfile.read().splitlines()`, so you get a list of lines. Then you could split each line by spaces using `line.split()`. You can customize what characters will be split with an argument, go read about python string methods.

Comment: But if I split something it becomes a list and split doesn't work on list types.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at it, tested on Python 2.x/3.x:

```
import re

def str2dict(filename="temp.txt"):
    results = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as cache:
        # read file into a list of lines
        lines = cache.readlines()
        # loop through lines
        for line in lines:
            # skip lines starting with "--".
            if not line.startswith("--"):
                # replace random amount of spaces (\s) with tab (\t),
                # strip the trailing return (\n), split into list using
                # "\t" as the split pattern
                line = re.sub("\s\s+", "\t", line).strip().split("\t")
                # use first item in list for the key, join remaining list items
                # with ", " for the value.
                results[line[0]] = ", ".join(line[1:])

    return results

print (str2dict("temp.txt"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should store the values as a list or a tuple. Something like this:

```
textname = input("ENter a file")
thetextfile = open(textname,'r')
print("The file has been successfully opened!")
thetextfile = thetextfile.read()
file_s = thetextfile.split()
holder = []
wordlist = {}
for c in file_s:
   wordlist[c.split()[0]] = c.split()[1:]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your file should look like this:

```
Part no.;Description,Price
453;Sperving_Bearin,9900
1342;Panametric_Fan,23400
9480;Converter_Exchange,93859
```

Than you just need to add a bit of code:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
reader = csv.reader(open('your_file.txt','r'),delimiter=';')
d = {row[0]:row[1].strip() for row in reader}
for x,y in d.items():
     print x
     print y
```